Checking if object is still cached in Google Earth Engine
I'm using the Python API of GEE and I'm building a mechanism to avoid re-exporting the data to GCS twice when the Python kernel dies in the middle of the transfer process (as a reminder: local -> GCS -> GEE).
Is there a way to identify if a process is still saved in the server cache and if yes is there a way to retrieve a unique identifier of the cached data (I don't need the data themselves, just a unique id)?
For example, if I run:
fc = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0").limit(2)
fc.getInfo()

and restart my kernel, is there a way to know that fc value are still cached?

If you want ot know if you already computed something on GEE (in my case if the function has already been launched in the past) I need to keep a reproducible identifier to place in my filename (I thought cahce was a goodf idea but Noël was right hash is better).
EZvery call to GEE can be represented as a json call to the API so if you do twice the same thing it should have the same json:
import ee
from ee import serializer 

fc = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0").limit(2)
serializer.encode(fc)

{
  "functionInvocationValue": {
    "functionName": "Collection.limit",
    "arguments": {
      "collection": {
        "functionInvocationValue": {
          "functionName": "Collection.loadTable",
          "arguments": {
            "tableId": {
              "constantValue": "FAO/GAUL/2015/level0"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "limit": {
        "constantValue": 2
      }
    }
  }
}

Now that is not the most convinient way to store information in a filename so you need to hash this json to a string.
One would naively use the hash method from python but be careful this method is randomized between Python session for security purposes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522626/hash-function-in-python-3-3-returns-different-results-between-sessions.
Instead we will use the hashlib module:
import ee
from ee import serializer
import hashlib
import json

fc = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0").limit(2)
hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(serializer.encode(fc)).encode()).hexdigest()
hash
>>>> '163c1fe4ab1b07aac37b005beb9622c81ed94a6e82f5fcea258001c7eaf8a211'

which will return consistent results between sessions. You can now use this number in your file convention and check beforehand that nothing has already been computed.

No part of the example you gave involves any significant caching on the server side. There is no unique ID to be had; nothing's kept in that example.
The only things that are kept longer than a few seconds for interactive queries  are aggregations (reduceRegion, etc), and requesting one of those twice will always get you the cached result.  The hash of the expression is the "ID" that you're asking about; you can't do anything with it, but the server will compute it and always ask the cache for it (unless you've turned off caching).
